# Angularjs form validation, based on serve response show error msg

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form in which I am checking if email is already exists. If it is already exists I am showing the error msg from json response. this part is done (this is i am checking when user click on submit button).

I am getting 409 error if email already exists.

I need to update email input filed. Need to add a msg That email  already exists. I am using ng-show="personalInfo.$submitted"

```
<form name="personalInfo" role="form" autocomplete="off">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" maxlength="11" class="form-control" name="usupiEmail" ng-model="usuAttributes.personalInfo.email" ng-focus="ShowPlaceholder('email')" />
    <label>Email ID</label>

    <div class="error-message" ng-show="personalInfo.$submitted" ng-cloak>
        Please verify your Email.
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn-default" ng-click="usupiUpdateUser()">Next</button>
```

I have tried different method also:

```
function checkWrongEmail (errorCode) {
    if (errorCode === '409') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How are you updating `personalInfo.$submitted` (by the way, you're probably misuing it, as it should be `usuAttributes.personalInfo.$submitted`?
When you get the response from the server with a 409 error, you can update this property with a `true` value. That way, it'll show the intended message for that error.

Answer (score 0):

First add the ng-app directive to the enclosing div. Without it will not work. I tried to manually put in true/false which did not work untill ng-app was set.
See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu7LadwL/). If you remove the ng-app from the form element it will not work. Whereas with the directive changing ng-show to true/false will give the desired result.

The ng-model you specified is:

```
usuAttributes.personalInfo.email
```

But the expression in ng-show is:

```
personalInfo.$submitted
```

You should check if this is in scope for the model
Also check if the fact that you defined your model on the input element which is immediately closed does not cause problems with access tot the variables(so again, has the error message div access to it?)